Add Identity Provider error after 1.11.3 update
Good afternoon
today I performed the update that I was asked to update packages within one of my projects and now it gives me the following error

I don't understand how I can solve it as I can't find resolution information or resolution information anywhere on the web
I hope someone can tell me how to fix it as I'm stuck
Thanks to everyone and good work

This is an English site. Please show the exception message in English, as text. Exception message etc. should be show as text and not as images anyway.
